# How to fetch multiple values and display in textbox from database on selection of <option> in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, database, jsp

1. My table is: **Users**  and it consist These columns.
   i). loginid
   ii). Name
   iii). FirstName
   iv). LastName
   v). Address

in the below we are populating **names** in the dropdown, once dropdown value changes, we need to print the correponding firstname,lastname,address,loginid  in the textbox.
this what we need to achieve

**This is my jsp code.**

```
        <%   DBConnection dbc=new DBConnection();   
             Connection con=dbc.getNewConnection();
             Statement st = null;
             ResultSet rs = null;
        try
        {
           st=con.createStatement() ;
           rs=st.executeQuery("select * from Users"); 
           %>
 
   <select id="selectBox" >

         <%  while(rs.next()){ %>
                <option><%= rs.getString(2)%></option>


      <%} %>
    </select>
    <input id="loginid" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="firstname" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="lastname" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="address" type="text" value="" />
```

So how to populate above 4 values based on selected **name** from the Users table.
Please help me how to write Javascript function to do that.

Comment: Hi, you can either submit form to server and load that datas or use ajax to do same.

Comment: @Swati, i am not aware about ajax, can you please provide some sample code for my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to write `onchange` event handler so whenever select-box value gets changes `this` handler will get called and then send the value of `select` to backend page(servlet) .So, ajax code will look like below :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  $('select#selectBox').on('change', function() {
     var value = $(this).val(); //get value from select-box
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',//can be post request or get 
        url: url,//put url here where you need to send
        data: {
          'value': value//pass value 
        },
        success: function(response) {
          //result will come here 
           //if recieve as html use           
          $("somedivclass").html(response)        
          //if recieve as separted commas         
          var result = response.split(",")
          //access same using result[0],result[1] ..etc
          //add value to input using
          $("#loginid").val(result[0]);
         //same for other  
    
        }
      });
    })
```

At your server end get that value which is passed from ajax using `request.getParameter("value")` inside `doPost` method of ajax if making `POST` request.Then ,simply write your query to retrieve record from db and send back same to ajax .So , your code will look like somewhat below :

```
String value = (String) request.getParameter("value");
String query = "select * from Users where yourcolumnanemtocompare=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, value);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
//if value there 
String text;
if (rs.next()) {
  //change value accordingly..i.e : rs.getstring..
  text = "<input id=" + loginid " type="
  text " value=" + rs.getInt(1) + " /><input id="
  firstname " type="
  text " value=" + rs.getInt(2) + " /> <input id="
  lastname " type="
  text " value=" + rs.getInt(3) + " /><input id="
  address " type="
  text " value=" + rs.getInt(4) + " />";
}

response.setContentType("text/html"); // Set content type 
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(text); // response to send back.
//or
if (rs.next()) {
  //change value accordingly..i.e : rs.getstring..
  text = rs.getInt(1) + "," + rs.getInt(2) + "," + rs.getInt(3) + "," + rs.getInt(4);
}
response.setContentType("text/plain"); // Set content type 
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(text); // response  to send back..
//or use json to send data..
```